# Graph user notifications. Get Post ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, comments

I'm starting to use the Graph API to get my notifications, and in the REST interface, they had the `object_id` field.  I used this to get the notification objects' id to then query the Graph for more information.

The Graph API object does not include this information.

Example of what I want to do:

1. Get user's notifications JSON object.
2. Grab single item
3. Identify if this item supports commenting/liking
4. Display comments and number of likes for that item
5. if user can comment or like item, display buttons for this

my process:

1. call `me/notifications/?include_read=1`
2. is pretty easy to do.
3. I can identify if the object refers to a group, event, random application, post, or photo using the URL.  I know that posts, likes, photos and others support commenting/likes so I have a way of doing this, though it involves parsing the `link` attribute of the item
4. this is what I need help with.  I can get the `id` of the object by parsing the `link`, but I don't get the full object some times using this.  For example, to post on a comment, you need to have `USERID_COMMENTID` and the link only has the `COMMENTID` in this form `http://www.facebook.com/USERNICKNAME/posts/COMMENTID`
5. I also need help with this.  I guess some fb objects can't been liked via the graph?

any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [notification FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/), which also replaced [the REST notifications.get API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.get/), still has an `object_id` column.  That's the closest thing that exists to what you're asking for.  It doesn't look like [the Graph API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#notifications) is documented to have the `object_id` field unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks :) I was playing with the `object_id` and for pictures, it is giving me unexpected results.  I take the id from the query and I put it in the graph url `https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>` and I get results like `false` or `(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: <ID>`.  Any thoughts?